# Intersection of Sylow $p$-subgroup of a group with subgroup of that group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

The following is a quiz question of abstract algebra and I am posting here as I was unable to answer it.

State True or false:Let $p$ be a prime number. If $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of some finite group $G$, then for every subgroup $H$ of G is $H\cap P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$?

Intutively, I think that this statement is true. But I am unable to prove it rigoriously.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me proving it rigoriously .

Comment: This is false. That is why you couldn't prove it.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Can you please give a counterexample?

Comment: The group $2^{1+24}:M_{24}$ is a counterexample, $p=3$.

Comment: Also $(2\cdot BM)\times Th$ at the prime $31$.

Comment: Umm.. Take any groups with two Sylow subgroups $P$ and $H$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Recall there might be multiple $p$-sylow subroups. Intuitively, imagine a subgroup $H$ which does not intersect (or which barely intersects) some $p$-sylow subgroup $P$. It might intersect a different $P'$ more, which would lead to $H \cap P$ not being large enough to be a $p$-sylow subgroup of $H$.

As a concrete example, take the symmetric group $S_5$. Consider the subgroup
$H = \langle (4,5), (3,4,5) \rangle$ which is isomorphic to $S_3$. The $2$-sylow subgroup of $H$ is $\langle (4,5) \rangle$, as that is the only subgroup of size $2$.

Now let's take a $2$-sylow subgroup of $S_5$. Say $P = \langle (1,2,3,4), (1,2)(3,4) \rangle$, which is isomorphic to $D_8$. Notice every element of $P$ fixes $5$. Now we see the issue! $P \cap H = \{1\}$! Every element of $P$ fixes $5$, but the only interesting element of $\langle (4,5) \rangle$ *doesn't* fix $5$.

Of course, there is a conjugate of $P$, say $P'$, so that $P' \cap H = \langle (4,5) \rangle$. Can you find it?

As a fun challenge, draw out the subgroup lattice of $S_5$ (using a computer! There's way too many to do by hand). Look at where $H$ and $P$ are in this lattice. Look at where $H$ and $P'$ are. To get started you should look at [this blog post](http://sheaves.github.io/Subgroup-Lattice-Color-Vertices/) which has most of the code already written. Unfortunately it's broken because of the python3 update from a few years ago, but it won't take much work to fix!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This statement is false,but if H is a normal subgroup of G,then H∩P is a sylow
p－subgroup of H.In order to write this proof,
You should note H is a normal subgroup and
Conjugacy of sylow p-subgroup.
And you also look Dummit &foote abstract algebra p 147